# QAbstractListModel + SectionScroller = Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, qt, list, segmentation-fault, qml

I'm using QML SectionScroller to scroll the QML ListView. When I use the SectionScroller a lot, I'm getting a Segmentation fault in

```
_ZN18QAbstractItemModel4sortEiNQt9SortOrder: ldrex r1, [r3]
```

Some important code

```
IrregularListWrapper::IrregularListWrapper()
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[Form0Role] = "form0";
    roles[Form1Role] = "form1";
    roles[Form2Role] = "form2";

    setRoleNames(roles);
    setLang(German);
}

QVariant IrregularListWrapper::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()) return QVariant();
    const IrregularVerb* verb = db->at(index.row());
    switch (role)
    {
    case Form0Role:
        return verb->getForm0();
        break;
    case Form1Role:
        return verb->getForm1();
        break;
    case Form2Role:
        return verb->getForm2();
        break;
    }
    return QVariant();
}

void IrregularListWrapper::setLang(Language l)
{
    QPluginLoader loader(plugins[l]);
    db = qobject_cast<AbstractIrregularList*>(loader.instance());

    switch (l)
    {
    case English:
        langName = "English";
        break;
    case German:
        langName = "German";
        break;
    }
    emit langChanged();

}
```

Why does this result in a Segmentation fault? Thanks in advance.

/edit: When normally scrolling there's a Segmentation fault too, backtrace is:

```
#0  QBasicAtomicInt::ref (this=0x18)
#1 QString (this=0xbe88d2a0, other=...)
#2 IrregularVerb::getForm2 (this=0x9e6de8)
#3 IrregularVerbWrapper::data(this=0x9e31b8, index=..., role=35) // the model
// some calls to libQtDeclarative
```

What is the problem? The IrregularVerb class looks like that

```
class IrregularVerb : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString form0 READ getForm0 NOTIFY formChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString form1 READ getForm1 NOTIFY formChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString form2 READ getForm2 NOTIFY formChanged)
public:
    QString forms[3];
    QString getForm0() const { return forms[0]; }
    QString getForm1() const { return forms[1]; }
    QString getForm2() const { return forms[2]; }
    IrregularVerb(QString a, QString b, QString c) { forms[0] = a; forms[1] = b; forms[2] = c; }
signals:
    void formChanged();
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the program in *your code* when the segfault occurs?

Comment: It does some JS code. Section Scroller uses a JS engine. Is there any way I can inspect the JS Code runtime in Qt Components?

Comment: The `SectionSroller` from Qt Quick Component is only meant for use with QML `ListModel` (it use `ListModel` functions like `get()`, `count`, etc), so if you want to use it with your own QAbstractListModel, you need to look into the SectionScroller code and modify it to suit your model.

Comment: I don't really have an idea what in the JS code can cause the crash. Could you give me some suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I think it is better not to use SectionScroller when you are using C++ model, if you are not familiar when the JS code.

Comment: I've just looked at the JS code, and the only calls to model are: model.count, model.get(...), and checking whether it's not null... May it be a thing of overusing the get function? (if the SectionScroller/FastScroll isn't overused, there's no crash)

Comment: found some backtrace, updated the post